# Mysql Join query using a group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm trying to write a query that will return ...

1. Each distinct user id in the accesslog table.
2. A count of how many distinct ip addresses each userid has accessed the site with, also from the accesslog table.
3. That userid's name, email address, and company name, from the users table.

I've got 1 and 2, but I'm not sure how to get 3. I suck at joins, I admit. :(

Here's the query I have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, COUNT(ipaddress) AS c FROM accesslog WHERE url LIKE 'www.example.com%' and userid != '' GROUP BY userid ORDER BY c desc
```

How would I `JOIN` in the other pieces of data that I want?

Comment: Ah cr@p... just remembered that my users table and accesslog table are in different databases, and I don't have access to a root mysql user. So I can't do this query after all.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to join to `users` table and add all its columns to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.userid, u.name, u.email, u.company, COUNT(a.ipaddress) AS c
  FROM accesslog a, USERS u
 WHERE a.userid = u.userid
   AND a.url LIKE 'www.example.com%'
   AND a.userid != ''
GROUP BY a.userid
ORDER BY c desc
```

Comment: I don't think you'll need 'DISTINCT' as the 'group by' should take care of that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it would have worked if my databases weren't so screwy.

Comment: @BoltBait - you're right; I've just copied / edited Ian's query and forgot to remove it. Will edit.